# Javascript - Set Required level doesn't work

Tags: javascript, crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I use JavaScript to set required level of field based on some selections, the field appears as optional but the form doesn't able to save and says please fill this field.

My code

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_field").setRequiredLevel("none");
```

I don't know why this happen i tried to hide the field using this code

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_field").setVisible(false);
```

it hides the field but when i press save the field appears again like a charm and cannot save the form.

Comment: Which entity and field?

Comment: Case entity and the field is lookup i created

Comment: To clarify, getControl = form actions (Disable, Visible...) getAttribute = value actions (get, set, required level...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script doesnt look quite right,

[setRequiredLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_setRequiredLevel)

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_field").setRequiredLevel("none");
```

[Visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_visible)

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("new_field").setVisible(false);
```